# cutting off outgoing http calls from servers

Tags: c#

I need a program or logic that captures all HTTP or HTTPS web requests from the server and add the specific timeout logic to that, Basically I want to cut all outgoing web calls such that my application performance increases without waiting, I am OK if I dint get response from some services withing certain time.

Comment: Hi bharath - do you have any code and attempts at solving this problem yourself? Are you using any frameworks to host your server? Which HTTP library are you using to communicate to the outside world?

Comment: You need to be clear whether you are want to place timeouts for HTTP calls made from your application or more generally on any application on your web server.

Comment: I have a .net application that calls many web services, so rather adding timeout to all service I want to add time out to all web services calls made from that machine